# Change Return Program

Tags: f#, functional-programming

My methodology is to attempt a problem using imperative code and then to attempt the same problem again using idiomatic functional code.

Here is the problem I am working through at the moment:

> **Change Return Program** - The user enters a cost and then the amount of money given. The program will figure out the change and the number of quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies needed for the change.

Here is my naïve (imperative) solution:

```
let cost = 1.10m
let amountGiven = 2.00m
let mutable change = amountGiven - cost

while change <> 0m do
    if change >= 0.25m then
        Console.WriteLine "quater"
        change <- change - 0.25m
    else if change >= 0.10m then
        Console.WriteLine "dime"
        change <- change - 0.10m
    else if change >= 0.05m then
        Console.WriteLine "nickel"
        change <- change - 0.05m
    else if change >= 0.01m then
        Console.WriteLine "penny"
        change <- change - 0.01m
```

How can I write this code using functional constructs (i.e. without `mutable`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case the easiest way to do it is to move the mutable variable into a functions argument and use recursion (the `while` just becomes the halting check for the recursion):

```
let cost = 1.10m
let amountGiven = 2.00m

let rec giveChange change =
    if change > 0 then
        if change >= 0.25m then
            Console.WriteLine "quater"
            giveChange (change - 0.25m)
        else if change >= 0.10m then
            Console.WriteLine "dime"
            giveChange (change - 0.10m)
        else if change >= 0.05m then
            Console.WriteLine "nickel"
            giveChange (change - 0.05m)
        else if change >= 0.01m then
            Console.WriteLine "penny"
            giveChange (change - 0.01m)
giveChange (amountGiven-cost)
```

this is the obvious translation

### simplification

Now of course the double `if`s are somewhat obsolete:

```
let rec giveChange change =
    if change >= 0.25m then
        Console.WriteLine "quater"
        giveChange (change - 0.25m)
    else if change >= 0.10m then
        Console.WriteLine "dime"
        giveChange (change - 0.10m)
    else if change >= 0.05m then
        Console.WriteLine "nickel"
        giveChange (change - 0.05m)
    else if change >= 0.01m then
        Console.WriteLine "penny"
        giveChange (change - 0.01m)
```

and of course the many `if`s look terrible as well - let's replace them with an list:

```
let coins = ["quarter", 0.25m; "dime", 0.10m; "nickel", 0.05m; "penny", 0.01m]
let rec giveChange change =
    match coins |> List.tryFind (fun (_,c) -> change >= c) with
    | Some (name,coin) ->
        Console.WriteLine name
        giveChange (change-coin)
    | None -> ()
```

I think that's a reasonable solution for now.

The none case will never happen, as we've got dimes in there (or so we hope, because if someone does not pay enough and the value becomes negative we are in trouble) - maybe we should give a somehwat better hint to this:

```
let coins = ["quarter", 0.25m; "dime", 0.10m; "nickel", 0.05m; "penny", 0.01m]
let rec giveChange change =
    if change < 0.0m then failwith "cannot change negative amounts"
    match coins |> List.tryFind (fun (_,c) -> change >= c) with
    | Some (name,coin) ->
        Console.WriteLine name
        giveChange (change-coin)
    | None -> failwith ("cannot find a coin smaller than " + string change)
```

### things to think about

- you don't really want to do the output in there do you?
- this is some sort of greedy algorithm - but why does it have to do the **division** by *repeated subtraction*?

Each of these would significantly change your algorithm so I will not show you more code but you should really think about the second:

Instead of doing "1.20 -> give quarter -> give quarter -> give quarter -> give quarter -> ..." it's easy to see that you have 4 quarters in 1.20 using mod/div in a clever way :D

Comment: @ildjarn oh doh ... it's early in the morning have merci ... but thanks

Comment: This was really helpful to me. Thanks bud.